# Can't resolve some dependency errors in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I was trying to install dependencies of a website and I get this error that I couldn't solve following some of the already published solutions.

Here is the error. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: samar@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0" from react-rangeslider@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-rangeslider
npm ERR!   react-rangeslider@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/intelligentica/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/intelligentica/.npm/_logs/2022-03-23T15_30_51_251Z-debug-0.log
```

The package.json file is here.

```
{
    "name": "samar",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev -p 5000",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "sass": "node-sass --watch scss/main.scss css/style.css --source-map css/style.css.map"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "next": "^10.0.6",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
        "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
        "react-modal-video": "^1.2.6",
        "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scroll-to-top": "^1.0.5",
        "react-slick": "^0.28.0",
        "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
        "simple-react-lightbox": "^3.6.6",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "use-scroll-position": "0.0.4",
        "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the package.json file as well?

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: What's the specific question? The issue is that `rangeslider` expects an earlier version of React; you can either check if `rangeslider` has more recent versions that support later React, or downgrade React. (Or tweak `rangeslider` and hope it works w/ later React.)

Comment: You have a lot of outdated versions there.

Comment: "Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated." https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Always check whether the npm package you're installing is (a) still supported, and (b) still up to date. The problem isn't that you're getting errors, the problem is that you've installed packages that don't work with modern React, so fix that (and that's just going to be you, actually verifying that each dependency you have in that package.json is something you can even use, by reading its npm page and github repo)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will check all these dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and install the dependencies using `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to delete the node-modules folder and make sure to install dependencies latest version by adding

```
npm i packagename@latest
```